# Chinese NER doesn't recognize some locations contained in Weibo texts

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm currently doing some work in classifying Chinese Weibo texts, in which one of the steps is to extract the Geo-locations contained in the texts. I followed the steps described in the Stanford-NLP website, i.e., use the Chinese Word Segmenter first to segment the Chinese text and then apply the Chinese NER model on the segmented text.

However, I've seen many false negatives where the texts do contain Geo-locations but the NER software fails to recognize them. Some examples are listed below (Italics are manually labeled Geo-locations).

> 【开展防汛排查】6月29日，*紫阳县红椿镇*强降雨引发了山体滑坡和泥石流，为避免发生不安全事故，*红椿*派出所与交警中队民警冒雨开展重点路段巡查，疏导交通，排查险情。目前，共排查险情3处，救助因山体落石被砸的伤员1名。@安康警务
>
> 【 开展/O 防汛/O 排查/O 】 6月/MISC 29日/MISC ，/O 紫阳/O 县/O 红椿镇/O 强/O 降雨/O 引发/O
>   了/O 山体/O 滑坡/O 和/O 泥石流/O ，/O 为/O 避免/O 发生/O 不安全/O 事故/O ，/O 红椿/O 派出所/O
>   与/O 交警/O 中队/O 民警/O 冒雨/O 开展/O 重点/O 路段/O 巡查/O ，/O 疏导/O 交通/O ，/O 排查/O
>   险情/O 。/O 目前/O ，/O 共/O 排查/O 险情/O 3/O 处/O ，/O 救助/O 因/O 山体/O 落石/O 被/O 砸/O
>   的/O 伤员/O 1/O 名/O 。/O @/O 安康/O 警务/O
>
> 【*云南*预警发布中心】*沧源县*气象台2015年7月16日14时00分发布暴雨蓝色预警信号：预计未来12小时，我县西部、南部的部分地区降雨量将达50毫米以上，请注意防范局地洪涝、滑坡和泥石流等灾害。
>
> 【 云南/ORG 预警/ORG 发布/ORG 中心/ORG 】 沧源/ORG 县/ORG 气象台/ORG 2015年/MISC
>   7月/MISC 16日/MISC 14时00/MISC 分/MISC 发布/O 暴雨/O 蓝色/O 预警/O 信号/O ：/O 预计/O
>   未来/O 12/MISC 小时/MISC ，/O 我/O 县/O 西部/O 、/O 南部/O 的/O 部分/O 地区/O 降雨量/O 将/O
>   达/O 50/O 毫米/O 以上/O ，/O 请/O 注意/O 防范/O 局地/O 洪涝/O 、/O 滑坡/O 和/O 泥石流/O 等/O
>   灾害/O 。/O
>
> 【*张掖肃南县*遭受山洪泥石流灾害 暂无人员伤亡报告】
>
> 【 张掖肃/PERSON 南县/O 遭受/O 山洪/O 泥石流/O 灾害/O 暂/O 无/O 人员/O 伤亡/O 报告/O 】
>
> *马尔康县*马江街红苕沟泥石流！
>
> 马尔康县/O 马江/O 街/O 红苕/O 沟/O 泥石流/O ！/O
>
> 走G214时候已经见过了陡坡，急弯，泥石流，滑坡，临水临崖，积雪泥泞等各种路况，今天出*左贡县*这段几十公里简直想骂娘，这种烂泥搓板路简直专治肾结石，哪儿结石都给你颠出来……
>
> 走/O G214/O 时候/O 已经/O 见/O 过/O 了/O 陡坡/O ，/O 急弯/O ，/O 泥石流/O ，/O 滑坡/O ，/O 临/O 水/O 临崖/O ，/O 积雪/O 泥泞/O 等/O 各/O 种/O 路况/O ，/O 今天/MISC 出/O 左贡县/O 这/O 段/O 几十/MISC 公里/MISC 简直/O 想/O 骂娘/O ，/O 这/O 种/O 烂泥/O 搓板/O 路/O 简直/O 专治/O 肾/O 结石/O ，/O 哪儿/O 结石/O 都/O 给/O 你颠/O 出来/O .../O .../O

One weird thing for the last example is that the online demo can correctly classify just the word "左贡县" by itself as GPE, while when I run it on my computer it will print "左贡县/O".

I don't know if I'm using the software correctly, and I don't know how I'm supposed to handle these problems if I'm using the software correctly. What can I possibly do to correct these? Like training my own model?

I really appreciate any helps.

Answer (score 0):

Has the Chinese character been embedded in your software? Lacking embedded font might be the problem.

Comment: Yes. I don't think this is what's causing the problem. Thanks.